# how do you pass arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

I have 2 classes. 1 class passes an ImageIcon[], and the other class takes the array and saves it.

These are the cut down versions of each class:

Class 1:
monsterLabel[] is an ImageIcon[]
saveLoad is is the name of Class2

```
ImageIcon[] toSave= new ImageIcon[button.length];
toSave[i]= new ImageIcon();
for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
toSave[i]=(ImageIcon) monsterLabel[i].getIcon();
}
saveLoad.saver(toSave[]);
```

Class2(saveLoad)

```
public void saver(ImageIcon[] buttonPic) {}
```

The Problem is in class 1, Eclipse tells me

```
   "Syntax error on token "[", Expression expected after this token"
```

where i'm passing toSave[]

when I put in a number ie. toSave[0], it tells me that class2 is looking for a ImageIcon[] not an ImageIcon.
How can I Pass an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just want:

```
saveLoad.saver(toSave);
```

Answer (score 5):

Just like this:

```
saveLoad.saver(toSave);
```

The fact that it is an array is already part of the declared type, so this fact doesn't need to be reiterated.  It'd be no different than if we had "int x".  We wouldn't call `someMethod(int x)` - we'd just call `someMethod(x)`.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `saveLoad.saver(toSave[]);` with `saveLoad.saver(toSave);`

You want to pass the variable, not part of the type with it.

Answer (score 1):

You do not put [] at the end of an array when passing it as a value. It should be:

```
saveLoad.saver(toSave);
```

Answer (score 1):

While passing parameters, you don't need to enclosing [].

```
saveLoad.saver(toSave);
```